# How to retrieve unclaimed BTC for wallets whose private key is lost

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key, wallet-recovery

How to retrieve unclaimed BTC for wallets whose private key is lost
Kindly share details

Comment: You need a private key to send the coins away. If you don't have the private key, you can't send the coins.

Answer (score 2):

If you lose the private key for some address that contains bitcoins, then you will never be able to spend those bitcoins. The private key is required in order to spend, and there is no known way to work backwards to discover the private key for an account.

If the private key is lost, the bitcoins become un-spendable.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoins are unspendable without the private key (as chytrik already stated). That being said, several wallets implement [BIP032](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032) which allows you to recover those private keys. It uses a "seed" (usually shown as several words) to initialize the wallet. Then the creation of the private keys is [deterministic](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet).
With this seed you would be able to "recover" your private key and therefore the unspent BTC.